# Email Verification Handler In Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm making API endpoints for email verification following the laravel documentation, and i'm having a problem with handling the email verification. The route that sends the email worked fine but the one to handle the request is giving me this error:

**Call to a member function getKey() on null**

this is the route:

```
Route::get('/email/verify/{id}/{hash}', function (EmailVerificationRequest $request) {
$request->fulfill();})->name('verification.verify');
```

and the stack trace shows me that my problem is in this method in the EmailVerificationRequest class

```
 public function authorize()

{

    if (! hash_equals((string) $this->route('id'),

                      (string) $this->user()->getKey())) { //specifically this line

        return false;

    }



    if (! hash_equals((string) $this->route('hash'),

                      sha1($this->user()->getEmailForVerification()))) {

        return false;

    }



    return true;

}
```

Comment: the verification system requires the user to be authenticated to verify their email, so that Request is expecting there to be an authenticated user, but you are not authenticated

Comment: i'm running the api with postman, does this require setting the bearer token? because when i do that it still gives me the same error

Comment: No actually i forgot to add the auth middleware to the route so now it works. Thank you very much!